# MySQL before insert trigger filling omitted column

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to make make a trigger, that will fill column B with value from column A if column B was not explicitly set in insert query. (column B is set to allow NULL and to default to NULL value)

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (NEW.valueB IS NULL) THEN SET NEW.valueB = NEW.valueA ;
END
$$
```

But I am getting this error (not very helpful).

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
```

When I tried to locate this problematic empty string '' making the query like one word per line, mysql marked the line with '=' character as problematic.

I double checked the query for any non-ascii characters.

I am using mysql version `5.5.37-0ubuntu0.12.10.1` through commandline (eg not phpmyadmin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the `IF` with `END IF`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON my_table 
FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
   IF NEW.valueB IS NULL THEN 
    SET NEW.valueB = NEW.valueA ;
   END IF ;
 END;$$
 delimiter ;
```

Check the example here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the IF statement. Read the syntax [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html). I think the code below will work for you.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON my_table 
FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
   IF (NEW.valueB IS NULL) THEN 
    SET NEW.valueB = NEW.valueA ;
   END IF 
 END $$
DELIMITER
```